# Check Point Software VPN fails (SSL Network Extender is down …) after Windows update

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssl, reboot, network-adapter

I am using Windows 10 in my Lenovo laptop. To connect to our client environment, I need to use their Check Point Software VPN.

I was able to connect successfully earlier in the day. However, after some Windows update, I have been repeatedly getting this error (see image)

I am using Internet Explorer. I have tried to run as Administrator. I have installed Java. Despite all these attempts, I am still not able to make my VPN work. Anything else I need to do ?

[image: error messages]
       [[Click for larger image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvEsb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out.

Installed this:

https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=10655

Then run Internet Explorer as an Administrator.

Comment: Sometimes, even after this I get this error:

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, even after the installation done above, I receive error:

> SSL Network Extender is down and could not be started. Consider rebooting the computer (#323)

**Solution:** Computer Management > Restart Check Point SSL Network Extender

- This service must be running [image: Service Manager]

Comment: It is interesting how many answers indicate other things to try rather than actually checking the service and try to start it if it is not running.

Comment: While the screenshot shows the following, this answer is incomplete as it's missing the requisite steps within Computer Management _(i.e. Computer Management > Services and Applications > Services)_.  It would likely be more efficient to `WinKey`+`R` > `services.msc` > OK

Answer (score 0):

On Dell Notebooks must be turned off the "Secure Boot" option in BIOS. Then works it.

Answer (score 0):

You need put extender.dll version 80.0.54.64 to "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files"
its works as user, not need rus as admin.